# How to Handle Modbus Broadcast Requests in Go using a Library?

Tags: go, tcp, modbus

I am working with Go, and I have a code that connects to a device using Modbus TCP. This device can receive Modbus broadcast messages using ID 0. However, when I use ID 0 to send a request, I don't receive a response, and my program fails with a timeout error.

I suspect that I might not be handling Modbus broadcast requests correctly. Is there any Go library or package that is well-suited for dealing with Modbus broadcast requests in Modbus TCP communication? If so, could you please provide guidance on how to use it to send and receive broadcast messages?

Comment: If by "broadcast request" you mean you are setting `Unit Identifier` to `0`, and the Modbus TCP server has RTU devices attached, then [as per the spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) "No response is returned to broadcast requests sent by the master". Please provide more information (saying "a library" is not useful; specify what library and show how you are using it). Note that requests for libraries is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).